# Convert Objective-C to Swift to Mock S3 Function continueWith

Tags: swift

I'm trying to Mock AWSS3

So I have a protocol

```
public protocol AWSS3Protocol {
    func listObjects(_ request: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest, completionHandler: ((AWSS3ListObjectsOutput?, Error?) -> Void)?)
}
```

That AWS conforms to:

```
extension AWSS3: AWSS3Protocol {}
```

and then my mock implements

```
class MockAWSS3: AWSS3Protocol {
    func listObjects(_ request: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest, completionHandler: ((AWSS3ListObjectsOutput?, Error?) -> Void)?) {
        //
    }
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is

```
        let s3 = AWSS3.s3(forKey: AWSServiceClientKey)
        s3.listObjects(listRequest).continueWith { [weak self] (task) -> AnyObject? in
}
```

and I'm stuck as I haven't been able to use continueWith

```
let listRequest: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsRequest()
listRequest.bucket = "bucketName"
listRequest.prefix = "folderName"

mockS3.listObjects(listRequest).continueWith { [weak self] (task) -> AnyObject? in
    guard let self = self else {return nil}

}
```

How can I implement continueWith for this?

The error is Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'continueWith' no matter if I pass nil as the completion handler, or expressly define a completion handler in the code.

Comment: What is the issue? One reason should be compile error when calling `listObjects` as you are not passing `completionHandler: nil`.

Comment: Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'continueWith'

Comment: Yeah, that is another legitimate error. Method declared in protocol `AWSS3Protocol` has no return type i.e, `Void or ()` so compiler is complaining. You can not call `continueWith` without its instance reference.

Comment: I understand that but in my code I have s3.listObjects(listRequest).continueWith and I want to replace the s3 with a mock. How is it done in the AWSS3 code?

Comment: You may need to introduce `continueWith` inside `AWSS3Protocol` and set `listObjects` return type as `func listObjects(_ request: String, completionHandler: ((String?, Error?) -> Void)?) -> Self`

Comment: continueWith is declared in AWSTask...whereas listObjects is in AWSService. I'm not clear how I can inject an AWSTask into the AWSService